# Rolling $20$ dice at least three six

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, probability-distributions, dice

If we roll $20$ dice, what is the probability of at least **three** six?

I solved by using $P(A)=1-P(A^C)$ property.
Considering the complement of problem, there is a $5/6$ probability of not rolling a six for any given die.
So the result is $1-{\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)}^{20}$ Am I thinking wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $1-{\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)}^{20}$ is the probability of at least *one* $6$

Comment: You probably need the binomial distribution here

Answer (score 1):

$$1-\binom{20}{0}\Big(\frac{1}{6}\Big)^0\Big(\frac{5}{6}\Big)^{20}-\binom{20}{1}\Big(\frac{1}{6}\Big)^1\Big(\frac{5}{6}\Big)^{19}-\binom{20}{2}\Big(\frac{1}{6}\Big)^2\Big(\frac{5}{6}\Big)^{18}$$

That is

$$1-\text{Probability of zero six's}-\text{Probability of 1 six}-\text{Probability of 2 six's}$$

Comment: I see , it makes sense now, thanks